# SoftHSM V2 lib file?

Tags: security, pkcs#11, softhsm

Using SoftHSM V2 for Windows which can be found at https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows on Windows 10 for use with PKCS #11.

Installed and can run the `softhsm2-util` successfully, but I cannot find a `.lib` file.

I can only find a DLL, no `.lib` file in any of the folders.

Am I missing something? Should it include a `.lib` file?

Comment: Should it? Well, do you need to include it as a static library? Are you going to recompile on bug fixes?

Comment: I will not be recompiling, but I assumed I needed it.

I guess this question is more about PKCS #11 than SoftHSM, so I will create another question.

Comment: You don't need `.lib`. See comments to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61595283/3868464).